# smash up? run out of cards

Tags: smash-up

Recently I was playing ninja-mages deck. After I gained 14 points my deck run out of cards.
What should I do when I can't draw cards anymore? (because my deck is empty)

Answer (score 8):

This is covered on page 4 of the [rules](http://www.alderac.com/smashup/files/2012/06/AEG-SU-Rulebook.pdf).

> If you need to draw or reveal a card and your 
>   deck is empty, shuffle your discard pile. Put it on 
>   the table face down—that’s your new deck. Start 
>   drawing from there.

If you have no discard pile as well, that would be a very odd game!  I've never seen a game go anywhere near that situation though.

Comment: That would pretty strange indeed. As you discard down to ten after drawing two cards at the end I see only two possibilities to empty both discard and deck: 1. all your creatures and permanent enchantments are placed at bases - but still they can't be counted yet or 2. you draw empty your deck and discard and hold the cards in hand BEFORE you have to discard down to ten.